# AppleScript Prompt User for Clicks

Tags: applescript, screen-capture

For my studies I use a lot the screencapture feature as a terminal command. Recently I started to use AppleScript to automate some of those screen captures. But now I would like to push the thing a bit further.

Is it possible to use a command such as "display dialog", but to query 2 clicks, of which the coordinates would be assigned to the screencapture command so that it takes the picture of the screen?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
set click1 to "0,0"
set click2 to "0,0"
display dialog "Click where the screen area to grab begins" & click1
display dialog "Click where the screen area to grab begins" & click2

do shell script "screencapture -R click1,click2 /Users/user/Desktop/name_of_the_file.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

Applescript does not have any mechanism for capturing mouse clicks, or even getting the position. You can get the mouse position using a call to the framework.
But, you will have to resort to a cocoa app solution to capture screen clicks.

One idea is you could use an applescript flow that gives you 2 seconds to place the first mouse position, then it can beep to tell you it has captured it, and then you have two more seconds to place the pointer in the second position before it captures it.
Something like this:

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

display dialog "Place your mouse pointer in the first position within 2 seconds, then after the beep, place it in the second position within 2 seconds."
delay 2
set theList to current application's NSEvent's mouseLocation()
set xCoord1 to theList's x
set yCoord1 to theList's y
beep
delay 2
set theList to current application's NSEvent's mouseLocation()
set xCoord2 to theList's x
set yCoord2 to theList's y
beep

display dialog (((xCoord1 as string) & ", " & yCoord1 as string) & return & xCoord2 as string) & ", " & yCoord2 as string
```